# What's the mechanism behind `(import nixpkgs) { ... }` in Nix flakes?

Tags: nix, nix-flake

I'm working to understand as much as I can about Nix flakes. I'm puzzled by the fact that a `nixpkgs` input is usually imported, and the imported value is called as a function. How does the result of `import nixpkgs` map to code in the `nixpkgs` flake?

It looks like this use of `nixpkgs` is common practice in flakes:

```hs
# flake.nix
{
  inputs = {
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable";
    /* ... */
  };

  outputs = { self, flake-utils, nixpkgs /*, ... */ }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = (import nixpkgs) {
          inherit system;
        };
      in
      {
        /* ... */
      }
    );
}
```

My understanding is that the `nixpkgs` value in this flake's `outputs` function is the attribute set produced by the `nixpkgs` flake. I understand that flake output is a derivation, and a derivation can be imported. But how does the imported value become a function? I expected it to be an attribute set.

I see that the [nixpkgs flake](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixpkgs-unstable/flake.nix) includes a `lib` output. Is there some mechanism where an attribute with a `lib` attribute path is callable? I have been looking for information on this, but I have not found anything.

If `(import nixpkgs) {}` is effectively calling that `lib` attribute, then how does importing differ from calling `nixpkgs.lib` directly? From what I've read importing a derivation has some effect on either forcing evaluating, or not forcing evaluation of something. I don't understand the details yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flakes behave like paths because of their `.outPath` attribute, which contains the flake source path that is automatically added to all flakes by Nix.

This lets [`import`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/builtins.html?highlight=import#builtins-import) load the file as a Nix value.

Specifically, because the path is a directory, it loads the [`default.nix`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/default.nix) in it, which then loads [`impure.nix`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/top-level/impure.nix), which contains a function.

Note that the way flakes are evaluated (without `--impure`), the evaluation is always pure, despite the "impure.nix" file name above.

The `.outPath` attribute got its name because it is also responsible for making derivations coercible to strings.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! So if I understand correctly, `.outPath` is automatically set on an input as part of the processing that the flake system does when loading inputs, and it is a file system path to directory in the Nix store where the flake is unpacked? I just read that coercing a derivation to a string also evaluates to the derivation's `.outPath` which explains some other things I've seen. And then the `import` doesn't work in flake mode, it uses the earlier system of loading `default.nix`. Ok, makes sense!

Comment: By "`import` doesn't work in flake mode" I think you mean `import` doesn't load `flake.nix`. I've clarified the answer based on your feedback.